# How to change DPI of part of a WPF/Silverlight application?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, zooming, dpi

I want my application to have a zoomable element which will allow the XAML elements to be viewed at 25%, 50%, 100%, 200% etc, I just need to alter the DPI of the XAML but am unsure how to do this on just part of the XAML (i.e. the element to zoom).
It will work just like the designer view in Visual Studio when you can zoom into the controls for more detail.
If there are other ways of doing this, then fine but it must zoom-in and zoom-out not just enlarge the canvas and keep elements the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a ScaleTransform on the element. A quick Google search brought [this](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=e3a9d402-a427-4304-b6be-93c60e82602b) up as a simple example. Or for more features there are a few articles around that recreate the DeepZoom feature from Silverlight in WPF - [this one](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2008/08/05/pan-and-zoom-deepzoom-style-in-wpf.aspx) for a start.

Comment: Thanks tried looking in a few places but could not find what I was after - this is what I needed, thanks!